# Threading in python - user input with timer

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I am trying to run two functions in parallel:

1. Timer
2. Input field

Program should terminate either when Timer ends or when user provides an answer.
Everything is working fine, but when the time is up I still can input an answer, and I want process to terminate.

Can somebody help me with that issue ?

Thanks !

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import time
import threading

def countdown2(seconds):
    global stop_timer
    stop_timer = False
    start = time.time()
    while not stop_timer:
        if time.time() - start >= seconds:
            stop_timer = True
            print(f'End of time {time.time() - start}')

    print(f'End of time in {time.time() - start}')


countdown_thread = threading.Thread(target=countdown2, args=(5,))
countdown_thread.start()

while not stop_timer:

    answer = input('Provide answer: ')
    if answer:
        stop_timer = True
        break

print('End')
```

Comment: This is because input() is blocking. Your thread may set stop_timer to True but you won't know that unless and until some input is given. Have you considered using a signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could do this:

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import signal
import os

got_input = False

def countdown(duration):
    global got_input
    for _ in range(duration):
        time.sleep(1)
        if got_input:
            return
    if not got_input:
        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)

def main():
    global got_input
    (t := Thread(target=countdown, args=[5])).start()
    try:
        answer = input('Please enter a value: ')
        got_input = True
        print(f'You entered: {answer}')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nToo slow')
    finally:
        t.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This code is ok, thanks for that, however it has one issue for me. Os.kill kills all the process, and what if after calling main() I want to do something more ?
My point is: I am creating a game (like how to become a millionaire). For each question user has only 5 seconds to answer. If time is up program should go to the next question. Do you have any idea how to deal with it :) ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @IgorRębas os.kill doesn't kill the entire process. It sends SIGINT which is handled as a KeyboardInterrupt (note how it prints 'too slow') once the signal has been observed. It's up to you how you continue processing from there on

Comment: Yes, but when I run your code and leave the time to pass by the output is:
Please enter a value: 
Process finished with exit code 2
So it doesn't print 'Too slow' at any moment...

Comment: @IgorRębas The code was tested on macOS. It's possible that signal handling is different on Windows. I would expect it to be the same on any *nix platform